# Using the heater in a temperature/humidity sensor

Tags: sensor, humidity

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the heater in a temperature/humidity sensor. The spec sheet for the [HDC1080](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fhdc1080) says

"The heater is an integrated resistive element that can be used to test the sensor or to drive condensation off the sensor. .... The heater helps in reducing the accumulated offset after long exposure at high humidity conditions."

I'm only interested in the condensation and accumulated offset. Attached to a microcontroller, how would the program know when to activate the heater? Does the humidity reading hit 100 percent when there's condensation? Is it neccessary to do a statistical analysis to know when the humidity has been high? Or should there be a button so the user can command the heater if the reading looks off?

Comment: Page 15 on datasheet, how to control heater. Do you want somebody to design algorithm for a you device?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the heater 24/7 there is the option of periodically energizing it, perhaps more frequently if there is a history of high RH readings. Or if the device is powered up for measurements you could run the heater every time it is powered up (possibly reducing the life, and certainly delaying the first accurate reading).

I don't see much guidance in the datasheet to answer your question, and it's certainly **heavily** application-dependent. You could look for an "application note" (I don't see any particularly relevant ones, but if I were you, I'd read every document listed on the [product page](https://www.ti.com/product/HDC1080?HQS=OCB-tistore-invf-partpage-invf-store-SnapEDA-wwe#tech-docs), including the manual for the evaluation board) and if nothing shows up, contact TI's application engineers, assuming you yourself have a clear idea of how you intend to use their devices. It also helps if you intend to use a large quantity of them, but for all users they have a forum-based support arrangement-- I've had mixed results in getting useful results in more intransigent problems.

Answer (score 1):

The heater option in bit 12 is a process **controlled by your uC algorithm**. That is only active during subsequent reads.  You might want to test the sensor under various conditions of still or moving air with the **tradeoff for power consumption and accuracy** above extended durations above 70%, such as when warm air makes contact with a cool sensor, creating condensation.

This draws an additional 7 mA only during the conversion time with heater bit enabled and is suggested to make frequent readings to see RH drop to a stable reading.  Consider this an impulse of heat.

### What causes condensation?

When warm air hits the cold surface, it reaches its dew point and condenses.

### What prevents condensation?

- Adding thermal insulation and air flow restriction to reduce the rate of change of air flow contacting a cooler surface below dew point.  But this adds latency to environmental sensor response with TBD specs, a compromise is possible by design.
- adding momentary heat to evaporate condensation in pulses so as not to raise temperature significantly between longer readings.  This requires heat calculations of sensor and heater trigger rates for different amounts of condensation accumulation and power budget with environmental protection requirements.

**There is no one algorithm to suit all designs.**

Specs:
[image]
Avoid condensation

[image]